# Constrained Optimization

Tags: python, scipy, minimize

I need to code a constrained optimizer. I am attempting to minimize the function *sub* which takes in the variable *rho*. *Rho* is an n-vector that needs to satisfy the constraint 0 <= *rho* <= 1. Below is what I have so far. I get the error 'Singular matrix C in LSQ subproblem' which makes me think that I have not defined my constraint function correctly. I know only the method COBYLA support inequality constraints but I don't know how to write it in that form. I have used 'eq' for the method SLSQP. Please help me!

```
def inequality(rho):
    return np.sum(np.logical_or((rho < 0), (rho > 1)))

cons = [{'type':'eq', 'fun': inequality}]

def opt2(sub):
    res2 = minimize(sub, rho(9), method='SLSQP', jac=gradient_ext, constraints=cons)
    return res2

optimize2 = opt2(subroutine_ext)
print(optimize2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help properly without knowing the function `sub` and its jacobian, anyway, there's no need to use any constraint in your case. It's enough to provide the variable bounds to `minimize`. Assuming `rho` is an numpy array:

```
bnds = [(0,1) for _ in range(len(rho))]

def opt2(sub):
    res2 = minimize(sub, x0=your_starting_point, bounds=bnds, jac=gradient_ext)
    return res2

optimize2 = opt2(subroutine_ext)
print(optimize2)
```

Comment: They are suppppppper long crazy objective functions. Sub takes in rho as a parameter and spits out a number while the jacobian intakes the same rho vector and outputs an n-vector. When I tried the above I got the error, "failed to initialize intent(inout) array -- expected elsize=8 but got 16 -- input 'D' not compatible to 'd'" Not quite sure what that means. Any insight?